# Nodemon not working using npm script from package.json on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, package.json, nodemon, npm-scripts

I'm working with NodeJS and Nodemon on Docker. When I try to run my NodeJS app using **nodemon** command directly in docker compose file, it runs.

Like this (working): [**docker-compose**]

```
command: nodemon source/index.js
```

But when I use a script from package.json, it doesn't work

Like this (not-working): [**docker-compose**]

```
command: npm run dev
```

Where my package.json file is

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node source/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon source/index.js"
  }
```

I tried different things, when I simply run start script without nodemon, it works

Like this (working): [**docker-compose**]

```
command: npm run start
```

But when I try to use **dev** again with **nodemon** command inside it, it doesn't work. Container won't start. I have also tried the following and it also works

Like this (working): [**docker-compose**]

```
command: nodemon --exec npm start
```

I still don't understand, why **nodemon** command is not working inside script **dev**

I'm using Docker in Swarm Mode

Here are my both files

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    node-service:

        image: node-img:1.0

        ports:
        - 4000:4000

        working_dir: "/node-dir"

        volumes:
        - ./node-dir/source:/node-dir/source

        networks:
            - ness-net

        command: npm run dev

networks:

    ness-net:
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-pkg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node source/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon source/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the "." to define the path in your package.json like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./source/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./source/index.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an environment variable to point on npm when running nodemon
`C:\........\npm` the path should be like this , and choose a name

Comment: I'm running this inside a docker, so where should I add environment variable? In Docker Container?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
services:
 node-app:
  container_name: node-app
  image: node:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./node/source:home/node/source
  working_dir: /home/node/source
  ports:
   - 4000:4000
  networks:
   - main-network
  command: "tail -f /dev/null && npm start"
  depends_on:
   - db
  logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
     max-file: "4"
     max-size: "100m
```

Here is package.json

```
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i nodemon -g",
  "start": "nodemon index.js",
}
```

Please make sure there should be index.js and package.json in working directory.

Comment: So what if I don't want to put  index.js and package.json in same working directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
just add in package.json--->>

"scripts": {
    "dev":"nodemon -L app.js"
  }

in docker file--->>>

FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5500

CMD ["npm", "run","dev"]
```

run cmd-->>

docker  build  -t  your_imge_name .

docker  run  --rm  -d  -p  5500:5500  -v  %cd% --name  your_container_name  your_imge_name